# VS2010 unit test try to start or load but never reaches code and never finishes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I have this auto generated test project from VS2010 to my winform application Form1 and the method i want to test is juat an int add(int x, int y) method:

```
[TestClass()] 
public class Form1Test
{


private TestContext testContextInstance;

public TestContext TestContext
    {
        get
        {
            return testContextInstance;
        }
        set
        {
            testContextInstance = value;
        }
    }    

[TestMethod()]
    public void addTest()
    {
        Form1 target = new Form1(); // TODO: Passenden Wert initialisieren
        int x = 0; // TODO: Passenden Wert initialisieren
        int y = 0; // TODO: Passenden Wert initialisieren
        int expected = 0; // TODO: Passenden Wert initialisieren
        int actual;
        actual = target.add(x, y);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        Assert.Inconclusive("Überprüfen Sie die Richtigkeit dieser Testmethode.");
    }
```

but when i go run tests, i see the test is running but nothing happens, i can´t even shut down or interrupt anything. What could be the problem or what is missing in my testproject??

Edit1: In debug mode the breakpoints can´t be reached because no symbols are loaded, and the call stack is empty

Edit2: When opening and running the same solution with tests in VS2012 everything  works but not in VS2010

Edit3: Seems like i always got an exception when trying to run th tests: "lost connection to the controller"

Update - After installing VS2010 SP1 now the tests run

Comment: What happens when you step through the code in the unit test? Is the `actual = target.add(x, y);` line reached? On which line of the code does the test *hang*?

Comment: what happens in constructor of Form1 ?

Comment: nothing the first line in the addTest method is never reached

Comment: Look at the Call stack when you are in Debug mode. What do you see there?

Comment: in debug mode the breakpoints are not full dot only circle which means they have no symbols loaded, the call stack is totally empty

Comment: @HenkHolterman The same problem exists no matter if the logic is in the form or in the controller even without the form the problem exists

Comment: Does the same problem persist if you put the business logic in a separate class library project that you would reference in your main project? Now you could unit test the business logic in isolation. It's what you should probably be doing anyway. But of course it doesn't explain the strange behavior you are observing. Maybe somehow Visual Studio got out-of-sync with the PDB files and cannot step through the code in your unit test.

Comment: Clean solution, Rebuild All in Debug Mode. Check for build errors and locked files that can't be deleted/rebuilt. If none, set a breakpoint on first line and make then trace thru each line in debugger. If not able to debug, shut down VS and reopen and repear from clean solution.

Comment: it exists when just having a class program.cs

Comment: @JayWalker did all of that but problem still happens

Comment: From all this it's not clear if you have any experience running and debugging Tests at all. What menu items do you use and what happens? Do you see the test-results window?

Comment: The problem is not the unit test or the fact, that you test a Form.
I have created a fresh C# WinForms solution, added a `int Add(int x, int y)` method in the Form1 class, right clicked this new operation and chose "Create unit test" and ended up with the pretty much the same unit test code as you did. If I run this test via *Test => Run => All tests in solution* the test finished with an Inconclusive result, just as expected.
This means, the error is hiding somewhere else. Maybe the form contructor is the problem, as Vlad already suggested.

Comment: like i said i tried the same without the form and again the test starts but nothing happens

Comment: @Gobliins - If you are not getting debug symbols, then chances are high that you have a build or test generation issue. Make sure your Error List window (View -> Error List or Ctrl+W, E) shows no errors and your Output window (View -> Output or Ctrl+W, O) shows the build was successful. Also, check {SolutionDir}\TestResults to see if folders are getting created there. It could be a permissions or disk full issue.

Comment: @saarp the directories are created and no errors ore warnings are in the vs views

Comment: this is some of the output when debugging the tests http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0MSG

Comment: @Gobliins - Heh. Taxing my very limited German abilities here. Are you testing a service call? Looks like you may have an issue with the service reference. Maybe just update the service reference in the test project?

Comment: @saarp no its just a normal c# application and the test method was created by right clicj on the add method -> creat component test

Comment: @Gobliins - Can you check that both test and assembly projects are being built for the same .Net version? Other than that, I'm kinda stumped. The reason no breakpoint is being hit is because the test is failing when writing back the "Test Starting" message. This should be a no brainer since it's not really running any of your code yet. Maybe this will help - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vststest/thread/df043823-ffcf-46a4-9e47-1c4b8854ca13

Comment: @saarp read the edit2, something in vs2010 does not work well, i will check out your link but i have less hope

Comment: ok now after installing the VS2010 SP1 everything seems to be wokring

Comment: Can you please post installing VS 2010 SP1 as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Somehow the problem fixed itself by installing the VS2010 SP1. After that everything worked.